# How to create a QML-Plugin in Visual Studio using the QtVsTools extension?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, qml, qt-vs-addin

To create a plugin in QT using a PRO file, just specify:

```
   CONFIG += plugin qmltypes
   QML_IMPORT_NAME=Geometry
   QML_IMPORT_VERSION=1
```

But there is no such thing in Visual Studio, I don’t understand how to make a plugin there.